# Utilizing more memory/CPU in vb.net application

Tags: vb.net, performance, cpu, ram

I have developed some code in vb.net to take user input from a command line, search through large log files (~10-40GB) line by line, and then output a thousand lines either side of the matched line to a text file.

The application is working, however it is only using a minimal amount of resources on my machine; around 28mb RAM/4GB & ~1% CPU/3.1GHz Dual Core I3) and takes a number of hours to search through a file, which is not ideal.

With resources not being an issue for this particular program, is there any way to increase the speed at which the file is searched through, or will there be an external limit for example disk read speed?

I know I may be missing something obvious here, but everything I've looked at seems to be about multithreading on complex programs with a lot happening at the same time.

```
 Sub SearchFile(ByVal FullPath As String, SearchText As String)

    Dim CurLine As Long = 0, FoundLine As Long
    Dim Timer As Long = 0
    Dim PerText As Integer
    Dim Found As Boolean = False


    Using ReadStream = File.Open(FullPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), objReader As New StreamReader(ReadStream)

        Do While objReader.Peek <> -1 And Found = False
            CurLine = CurLine + 1
            'Displays Percentage of file searched.
            If CurLine > Timer + 50000 Then
                Console.Write(vbBack & vbBack & vbBack)
                PerText = (objReader.BaseStream.Position / objReader.BaseStream.Length) * 100
                Console.Write(PerText & "%")
                Timer = CurLine
            End If

            If InStr(objReader.ReadLine, SearchText) 
                FoundLine = objReader.BaseStream.Position
                Found = True
                ReadLines(FoundLine, FullPath, SearchText)
            End If

        Loop
        objReader.Close()
    End Using
    If Found = False Then MsgBox("Not Found")

End Sub
```

Comment: What does ReadLines do? I don't think you can get much better than that. Maybe you could get it a bit faster with two threads, one that read big chunks of the file while the other parse the previous chunk.

Comment: This is an IO bound computation. The limit here is the disk. Try reading big chunks of data at a time, with an async API. While loading the next chunk process the current one.

Comment: @the_lotus Readlines just takes the position of objReader.BaseStream.Position, and reads a chunk of the file 1000 lines before and after by reading each line (objReader.ReadLine) into a variable. This may or may not be the most efficient method but it accounts for such a small amount of the running time after the position has been found it shouldn't matter too much.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks, that sounds like what I'm looking for. What size chunks would you suggest reading for best efficiency? Or is there anywhere you can point me to that may have some more information?

Comment: @Snibs maybe you should think of caching the previous 1000 lines and read the file forward only. Opening a file for reading forward only is faster than having a foreward/backward.